# Storing a colour in a variable for future use

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console

I am writing a bit of a dungeon crawler as I learn my way through c#. I am using visual studio and the application is a "Console App (.NET Framework)". My problem is that I have an option in the main menu to change text colour and I am trying to find away to make this change all the other times I change the colour so that it returns to a set default.

I have tried to assign the colour to a variable, lets say, default and then do the Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.default; I looked online everywhere and can't find a fix.

```
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        Console.WriteLine("example");
        Console.ForgroundColor = Console.Color.White;
        //             This needs to be default ^^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a property that will of `ConsoleColor` which will considered as a default color.

Just Assign it when ever you want default color should set to `Console.ForegroundColor`

Something like,

```
public class Program
{
    public static ConsoleColor DefaultColor { get; set; } = ConsoleColor.Black;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        Console.WriteLine("example");

        //You can use DefaultColor whenever you want to assign default color to Foreground
        Console.ForegroundColor = DefaultColor;

    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what does the get; set; do?

Comment: `DefaultColor` is a property. get and set are getter and setter which used to read property value or setting value to the property. For more information you can read: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties

Comment: How would I change the Console colour in the DefaultColor method from the Main method?

Comment: You can assign new value to it. something like, `DefaultColor = ConsoleColor.White`;